# PHPMailer Cannot send emails on live server

Tags: php, email, smtp

I believe this question has been asked before, but I couldn't seem to find a solution to the problem.

I'm using PHPMailer to handle emails on a website. Everything works fine on localhost, but it doesn't work on a live server. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMPTSecure='tls';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->Username='*********';
$mail->Password='*********';

$mail->setFrom('*********', '********* Booking', 0);
$mail->addAddress('*********');

$name = "First Name :" . $_POST['firstname'] . "<br>";
$email = "Email :" . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";
$number = "Contact Number :" . $_POST['number'] . "<br>";
$message = "message :" . $_POST['message'] . "<br>";
$truck = "Truck Selected :" . $_POST['item'] . "<br>";


$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject='********* Booking';
$mail->Body= "$name $email $number $message $truck";


if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  header('Location: /index.php');
  echo 'Message was sent.';
  exit;
}
```

Sending the email on the live server using the above code results in the following:

```
2020-01-22 07:51:48 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
2020-01-22 07:51:48 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused) [/websites/cv/*********/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 299]
2020-01-22 07:51:48 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

However, If I disable `$mail->IsSMTP();`, which some people have suggested, the error doesn't display, but the emails are not being sent/received.

**Things I have tried:**

- Using ssl, port 465
- Turned on less secure apps on the sending email
- Contact my host asking if any of the ports are blocked, they
  said they were not
- Made sure openssl was active
- Made sure the login
  credentials are correct

After doing all these things, it still says connection refused when using SMTP. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a network/sysadmin problem, not a PHPMailer problem.Try

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587  // host and port
```

in your console, for checking conectivity. If everything is working ok, it should write a message like 'ESMTP MAIL Service ready'. Otherwise that server is blocking yours.

Comment: I receive this on the server when checking the port
`Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused)`

Localhost gives me a successful connection. I guess it is the host

Answer (score 0):

Please add class smtp in your file or use this code and change credentials accordingly it will work.

```
include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

 require_once('class.smtp.php');

$name = strip_tags($_POST['full_name']);
$email = strip_tags ($_POST['email']);
$msg = strip_tags ($_POST['description']);

$subject = "Contact Form from DigitDevs Website";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "info@example.com"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;

$mail->AddAddress('info@example.com', 'Information'); 
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Wale');

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->Body    =  $msg;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
 echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: Port 26 seems to give a continuous load time, and doesn't submit the form at all. I added class.smtp.php and tried it with port 587 again, but the same connection refused error is occurring.

Comment: this is the the error when you trying to connct  "unable to connect to server Connection refused "

Comment: Yes, with your solution the same error happens, the one posted in my original post. I'm going to try the same script on another server, to see if its the host thats causing the block

Comment: This sounds like a network/sysadmin problem, not a PHPMailer problem. Try a

"telnet hostname port"

in your console, for checking conectivity. If everything is working ok, it should write a message like 'ESMTP MAIL Service ready'. Otherwise that server is blocking yours.